# The applet based program is getting executed but i am unable to get a applet window

Tags: java, applet

I have worked with a program to find factorial of a number its getting compiled successfully without errors and is evening running but I cant find a applet window out of it to find my solution.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.String.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
/*</applet code="Fact.class",height=200 width=200></applet>*/
public class Fact extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    String str;
    Button b;
    TextField t1,t2;
    Label l1,l2;
    public void init()
    {
        Panel p=new Panel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(l1=new Label("Enter integer"));
        add(t1=new TextField(20));
        add(l2=new Label("Factorial value is"));
        add(t2=new TextField(20));
        b.addActionListener(this);              
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int i,n,f=1;
        n=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            f=f*i;
        t2.setText(String.valueOf(f));
        repaint();        
    }
}
```

can I know what all the changes I have to make.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your Panel p to the applet, and add the other graphical components to the panel.